# Eclipse debugger is blank (source not found)

Tags: java, debugging

im trying to debug the following code, and i have breaked at line `w= w+ inputString.substring(firsti,i)+"yay";` but debugger shows blank (source not found) what's going on?

```
public String translate (String inputString) 
{ 
    String w = "";
    int firsti =0;
    for(int i=0; i< inputString.length(); i++){
        if(isVowel(inputString.charAt(i))){
            firsti = i;
            while (inputString.charAt(i) != ' ' || i< inputString.length()){
                i++;
            }
            w= w+ inputString.substring(firsti,i)+"yay";
            System.out.println(w);
        }
    }
    String outputString = new String(inputString); // Copies input to output and prints it. 
    return outputString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be trying to get into `substring()` method which is inside java API. You need to attach Java source to debug `substring()`

How to attach source:

Go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and expand JRE System Library JRE Version then, rt.jar. Select Source attachment, click Edit…. Select the source code file (External File…) and press OK

Read this [link](http://www.cavdar.net/2008/07/14/3-ways-of-jdk-source-code-attachment-in-eclipse/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your source code in the debug configuration:

Perform the Steps below:

Option1:

```
Right Click(Java Source) -> Debug As -> Java Applications
```

Option2:  If option1 doesn't help:

```
Menu ->Run ->Debug Configurations..-> Java Applications -> RightClick & select New
In right side, 
       Enter Name
       Browse your Project and the class having `main` method
       In Classpath, add your project from workspace
Click Debug button in the bottom
```